# Blazor Server can't click select element from javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor

On a blazor page, I have a html select element.

```
<select class="form-select" @bind="Model.ItemId">          
   @foreach (var item in Items)
   {
     <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
   }
</select>
```

Using **IJSInterop**, I am calling a javascript function to focus on the select element, and then try to click it.

```
    ...
    select.focus();

    var activeElement = document.activeElement;
    activeElement.click();
```

Everything seems to work fine, except when the select element is "clicked" the options don't show on the screen.

I don't know if blazor makes any difference from standard html in this scenario. Any ideas?

Comment: Changing active components that are "controlled" by the Blazor DOM often breaks them.  What are you actually trying to do?  There's probably a Blazor way to do it.